# Wordpress wp_redirect only once for users from Country

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

**Trying to achieve a situation on a Wordpress site:**

- when user is from countrycode EE then redirect him to url /et but only do it **once** so the user could still visit the original language as well /

Added my code into the functions php with an `add_action` but I get an infinite loop
My code is as follows:

```
function wpml_lang_redirect() {

    if(isset($_SERVER["MM_COUNTRY_CODE"])){
        //If it is exists, use it.
        $userCountry = $_SERVER["MM_COUNTRY_CODE"];
        //$euroCountry = array('EE');
    
        if( $userCountry == 'EE' ) {
            wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('url') . "/et/" );
            //wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('url') . "?lang=en" );
            exit;
        } 
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpml_lang_redirect' );
```

I also don't want to put this on the homepage as I want to redirect users once but still be able to switch to the original homepage for ENG content.

Currently a bit confused how could this be even achieved? or would this rather be something to .htaccess type of assignment and not PHP?

Comment: The thing that I tell all of my clients, is that unless you have a _site_ dedicated to a region/language/etc., _don’t_ redirect. Instead, pop a message up using JS that says “you are visiting the XYX page, but you might be interested in the ABC page instead”. Redirects confuse users (and bots), and this gives them control.

Comment: You would have to store the information that you redirected the user somewhere - in a way, that it will be accessible again at that point. So that would usually be a job for a cookie. (Only problem, if the user did _not_ accept cookies, you'd still have a redirect loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution with PHP, with setting a cookie

```
if( !isset($_COOKIE["first_time_estonia"]) ){
    $browser_lang = $_SERVER["MM_COUNTRY_CODE"]; // from server provider
    setcookie("first_time_estonia", "1", time() + 24 * 3600, "/", "", 0); // for 24hrs

    if( !isset($_COOKIE["first_time_estonia"]) ){   
        header("Reload:0"); // has been here in 24hrs doesn't redirect again
    }
    if ($browser_lang == 'EE') {
        header("Location: /et"); // hasn't been in 24hrs redirects to Estonian
    }
}
```